# Python extension debugging

Tags: python, gdb, debug-symbols, python-extensions

I'm trying to debug an extension module for python that I wrote in C. I compiled it using the following:

```
python setup.py build -g install --user
```

I then debug with:

```
gdb python
...
b py_node_make
run test.py
```

It breaks at py_node_make (one of the functions I defined), but then I try:

```
(gdb) print node
No symbol "node" in current context.
```

The function I'm trying to debug is:

```
static Python_node_t* py_node_make(
        node_t* node)
{
    Python_node_t* pyNode;

    pyNode = PyObject_New(Python_node_t, &t_node);
    pyNode->node = node;
    pyNode->borrowed = true;

    return pyNode;
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For source debugging to work, your C extensions must be built with debug info (`gcc -g`). Since you're driving the compilation process with `distutils`, you can specify the compiler flags used through the **CFLAGS** environment variable ([Installing Python Modules: Tweaking compiler/linker flags](http://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#tweaking-compiler-linker-flags)):

```
CFLAGS='-Wall -O0 -g' python setup.py build
```

Note that even if distutils defaults to a higher optimization level than **-O0**, you really shouldn't get that *No symbol "node" in current context* error as long as **-g** is passed and most Python builds do pass **-g** by default.

Comment: I believe the trouble was that the function was completely optimized out. I know the -g flag was set because other functions here and there and plenty of information, just not py_node_make.

Comment: I see. py_node_make() was a small static function and a prime target for inlineing. Setting a breakpoint on it still worked, but the argument name **node** is lost.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the optimization. I'm not sure how to do it from the command line, but in the setup.py script I just added `extra_compile_args=['-O0'],` to the Extension constructor and everything worked.

Would still like (and would accept) an answer that involved a command line arg (something after `python setup.py build`) that would accomplish the same thing so I don't have to have a compiler specific line in my setup.py file.