# How do you tell setuptools to build an extension for --debug when using pyproject.toml / PEP 518

Tags: python, c++, setuptools, debug-symbols, python-extensions

I have created [a Python project with a C++ extension](https://github.com/OddSource/ifaddrs4u/tree/main/ifaddrs4py) using `pyproject.toml` (PEP 518, PEP 517, PEP 621, PEP 660, etc.). I'm sure I could be doing some things better, but generally speaking it's working great.

In typical cases, this project will be built **without** C++ debug symbols, which is the default for Setuptools and works as I'd expect. However, for troubleshooting purposes, I want to document a process for building the project **with** debug symbols. Even if not specifically attaching a debugger, debug symbols can be helpful for diagnosing crashes, if/when they occur.

I have tried various incantations to `pip install`:

- `--debug`: silently ignored, library still built with `-DNDEBUG -g -O3`
- `--global-option --debug` ("WARNING: Ignoring --global-option when building ifaddrs4py using PEP 517" and "DEPRECATION: --build-option and --global-option are deprecated")
- `--config-setting="--global-option=--debug"`: fails with "error: option --debug not recognized" after first emitting "SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: Incompatible `config_settings` passed to build backend."
- `--config-setting="--build-option=--debug"`: no warning, but still fails with "error: option --debug not recognized"
- Adding `[build_ext] \n debug = 1` to `pyproject.toml` like you would normally add to `setup.cfg` ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61692952/how-to-pass-debug-to-build-ext-when-invoking-setup-py-install))

The [Setuptools documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/ext_modules.html) doesn't provide instructions on this is far as I can find.

I've seen several suggestions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253586/python-extension-debugging)) to use `python setup.py build -g` or `python setup.py build --debug`, but this is [a deprecated way](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html) to use `setup.py` under the above PEPs.

Is it not possible under this new standard to build Python extensions with debug symbols? If it is, how to do this?